# Macbook Air 13 - Stuck mid-bar at login, after reinstalling system stuck on apple logo

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, macos, startup

My Macbook Air 13 has crashed today.

I've been playing some games on it and the screen suddenly got stuck. After waiting for about 15 minutes I turned it off the hard way (power button hold), unfortunately after rebooting once i entered password for account it got stuck at about 75% of bar. This happened about 5 times before i decided to enter CMD+R boot menu, erased the disk, created new partition with GUID scheme and installed MacOS Scierra.

Instalation went fine, but after Internet Recovery it got stuck forever on Apple logo with about 60% of bar loaded. Rebooting brings no diff.

Is there any way to repair it apart from warranty service?

Comment: Honestly that sounds an awful lot like a drive error. If you can get into recovery mode run disk utility and a repair, faililing that I would be tempted to take it in.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks for response, I have actually run disk utility twice already, but will give it a go one more time and let you know in a moment

Comment: @SteveChambers just managed to repair drive again - still no progress. I just noticed when the bar with apple logo stops moving there comes a VoiceOver sound notification, then it just wont load more and i stuck + fan is really noisy

Comment: woah, it suddenly went to language choice screen but it is unclickable and black screen appears every now and then

Comment: Sounds like Disk Utility is freezing. I would bet it's a hardware issue.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have managed to repair the SMC thing and it booted - however when there are more graphic elements rendering on screen like FB wall white strips blink all over the screen - probably you are right and somehow the graphic card might have been damaged... thanks for your help anyways!